# Make sticky header expand when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a sticky header which javascript I found on Internet. The script is working just fine but I want to add an additional feature to it. When an icon is clicked I want the header to expand and whenever the page is scrolled again to retract again.
The problem is that I have just basic experience with javascript and some additional code must be added. I hope that some of you may help me.

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 50,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
        });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: We won't write your code for you, you write it and then we help fix **specific issues** if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another day behind the screen and I came to the following solution.

```
 <script>
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 50,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
            expand = document.getElementById("MyDiv").addEventListener("click", function(){
               if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
});
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
        });
}
window.onload = init();
</script>
```

It works like magic (exactly how I want to). Although I really have no idea about javascript so I will be grateful if someone more experienced has it checked and let me know if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
 function init() {
var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 50,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
         });

         document.getElementById("yourdiv").addEventListener('click', function(e){
                 if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, the change you made seems to break the code so the header doesn't work any more. May be it interferes with the other javascript which is in a separate file. Anyway thanks for you efforts guys.